# Is there a way to specify the location of nuget.config for the mdbuild run?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a C# .Net *.csproj that I need to build but it cannot find the right source for the nuget restore task (`<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>`). Is there a way to specify the location of `nuget.config` running msbuild on a *.csproj file?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? Is this a .net core / .net standard project?

Comment: vs 2015, standard .net

Comment: What kind of package restore are you using? the `.nuget` folder containing projects & targets? is it failing to use a NuGet feed or cannot import a target / task? a bit more context and exact error messages would be helpful